# How to solve a zero order Bessel function equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, bessel-functions

The equation is I<sub>0</sub>(a*x)=b, where a,b are constants, and I<sub>0</sub>(y) is zero order bessel function.

**I<sub>0</sub>(x)=1/(2*pi)*integral(x*cos(t)) dt   [from 0 ->2*pi]**

I want to get the value of  x when a and b are given. I just want the result, so it's not necessary to implement the solving procedure all by Matlab, and an approximate answer is fine, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselj.html, http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)

```
x = fsolve(@(x)(besselj(0,a*x)-b),x0);
```

or using a simpler solver as pointed in the comment below (http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fzero.html)

```
x = fzero(@(x)(besselj(0,a*x)-b),x0);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `fsolve` to to find what looks to be a univariate root? `fzero` would suffice, would be more efficient, and in some cases, more robust. Also, this is a rather poor quality answer in terms of explanation and formatting.

Comment: Just typed something off the top of my head :). Tnx, answer updated